# Persist the ACE editor UndoManager across sessions

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I would like to persist the [Ace Editor](https://ace.c9.io/)'s `UndoManager` instance across browser sessions, the way the [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/) seems to.

I have tried to stringify the `UndoManager` object so that I may store it somewhere to later retrieve it like so:

```
 let undoManager    = editorHTML.getSession().getUndoManager();
 let undoManagerStr = JSON.stringify(undoManager);
```

But the stringify call throws the exception `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

I've also tried extracting pieces of the object for storage:

```
 let redoStackStr       = JSON.stringify(undoManager.$redoStack, null, 2);
 let undoStackStr       = JSON.stringify(undoManager.$undoStack, null, 2);
 let dirtyCounter       = undoManager.dirtyCounter;
```

.

```
 let manager = new ace.UndoManager();
 if(redoStackStr && undoStackStr && dirtyCounter) {
      manager.$redoStack = JSON.parse(redoStackStr);
      manager.$undoStack = JSON.parse(undoStackStr);
      manager.dirtyCounter = dirtyCounter;
 }
 editorHTML.getSession().setUndoManager(manager)
```

But Ace doesn't like this at all and bombs out on CTRL-Z

I would prefer not to have to write my own file history manager when one already exists.

**Edit**

I was able to solve this using the answer selected below, but only after upgrading to Ace editor version 1.4.2.  The above code was my attempt after analyzing the `UndoManager` in version 1.2.8, which is why it's so different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ace 1.4 the second method you mention works, the only problem in your example is that dirtyCounter is undefined

```
UndoManager = require("ace/undomanager").UndoManager
undoManager = editor.session.$undoManager
var str  = JSON.stringify({ 
    $redoStack: undoManager.$redoStack,
    $undoStack: undoManager.$undoStack,
    mark: undoManager.mark,
    $rev: undoManager.$rev,
 })
 var manager = new UndoManager();
 if (str) {
     var json = JSON.parse(str)
      manager.$redoStack = json.$redoStack;
      manager.$undoStack = json.$undoStack
      manager.mark = json.mark
      manager.$rev = json.$rev
 }
 editor.getSession().setUndoManager(manager)
```

But note that this will fail if you do this for sessions with different values.

Comment: Great to know this can work - I'm a little confused as to how dirtyCounter is undefined in my example.

Comment: which version of ace do you use? dirtyCounter was in one of old versions but was removed later.

Comment: I've upgraded from v1.2.8 to v1.4.2 and your code is now working for me.  Thanks.